# Show default Drilldown in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts, drilldown

How do I load a given drilldown by default in Highcharts? I'm using a piechart to display the data.

I've tried triggering a click function on the path element but that doesn't work.

```
$('.highcharts-drilldown-point:first').click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger a drilldown on a point by calling `point.doDrilldown()`.

To do it by default you could for example:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                this.series[0].data[0].doDrilldown();
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Or see [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/995shwqe/).